# Creating Log in with .NET Core 3.0

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, orm

I am developing a .NET Core, windows app with a PostgreSQL database and Entity Framework Core (ORM).
I have been trying to create logging in with username and password but I don't know how to bite it.

I have created roles in my database and table "User" with a username and hashed password column.
My main idea is to try to insert a username and password through UI, hash the password, create query checking the hashes, and here is my **main problem** I don't know what I should do when the passwords will match meaning that login was successful. Succesful login would somehow let the user of the app get a specific role in dB, that enables to read data **from rows that match only one primary key of the user**.

I don't know how to achieve this behaviour I thought that maybe using some kind of connection string for DbContext that have login and password of the user would be useful but I honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure how to setup the password handling for a Logged in functionality. Don't do it yourself, there are a lot of footguns and could go very badly. Use .Nets [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio), that will give you a good handling for these things.